Как получить seed фразу при создании кошелька tron-php
Использую tron-php для создания кошельков в моём laravel проекте, однако при создании отдаётся только приватный ключ и адрес. Возможно ли получать Seed фразу и если да, как это сделать?
$uri = 'https://api.trongrid.io';// mainnet
$api = new Api(new Client(['base_uri' => $uri]));
$trxWallet = new TRX($api);
$addressData = $trxWallet->generateAddress();
// $addressData->privateKey
// $addressData->address
$user = TelegramUser::create(
    [
        'telegram_id' => $userId,
        'username' => $username,
        'balance' => 0,
        'address' => $addressData->address,
        'private_key' => $addressData->privateKey, 
    ]
);   

